# Detecting navigation to <a name="latest-topics"></a>

Tags: javascript, hash, navigation, location, anchor

I need to detect some event in which an URL navigates to an anchor:

```
<a name="latest-topics"></a>

http://someserver.com/index.html#latest-topics
```

And then I would like to use some event of the kind of `onfocus`, `onclick`, etc.

```
<a onclick="doSomething()" onfocus="doSomething()" name="latest-topics"></a>
```

What options are there to detect navigating to such anchor in the precise event of navigating to it?

Or would I need a timer with `setInterval` to continuously poll changes to `location.hash` every few milliseconds?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this onload:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
 // do your check here.
}
```